# converting bitmap to byte[] & writing byte[] to file : illegalArgument exception

Tags: android, bitmap, io

```
 public static void writeBitmapWithCompress(final String localFileName, Bitmap b){
        int bytes = b.getByteCount();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
        b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer
        byte[] array = buffer.array();
       // byte[] encodedString  = Base64.encode(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
       // Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

        Timber.d(">> social localFileName"+ localFileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFileName);
            fileOutputStream.write(decodedString);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

getting exception at this line -->  `byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(array, Base64.DEFAULT);`
bad base64. Is other way to do this task without using any compression ?

stacktrace--- >

> at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) 
>       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) 02-08
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
>    I/dalvikvm:
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
>   at nl.changer.socialschools.common.Utils.resizeImage(Utils.java:408)
>   at nl.changer.socialschools.common.Utils.uploadPhotos(Utils.java:321)
>   at nl.changer.socialschools.AsyncPostService.createPost(AsyncPostService.java:75)
>   nl.changer.socialschools.AsyncPostService.onHandleIntent(AsyncPostService.java:50)
>    at
>   android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 02-08 
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 02-08 11:41:36.214
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: show the full exception stacktrace and message. It explains the problem usually.

Comment: You should `encode` the bytes to a base64 string. Not `decode` as you try to do now.

Comment: But why do you want to use base64? You can write the byte buffer directly to file.

Comment: If I don't decode then I was unable to see image in gallery. Do you have any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 public void writeBitmapWithCompress(final String localFileName, Bitmap b){

    byte[] image_bytes = getBytes(b);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localFileName);
        out.write(image_bytes);
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


// convert bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: don't want to use compression. Want to write file directly.